# Wordpress in docker only has text

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, ubuntu

Maybe the CSS does not work?
Following has only text.
[image]

Following has only text.
[image]

My situation is similar to the issue in this link, but following what he said doesn't work for me.

https://serverfault.com/questions/893706/docker-with-wordpress-mysql-nginx-no-styles-in-wordpress

I have changed the browser, cleared the cache, but it still doesn't work. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: It seems some of your resources like css, js, images are not loaded properly. Check you network tab in developer console.

Comment: yes,it says NO data found for resource with given identifier

Comment: That's an issue with it. Make sure all the required file are loaded properly